# Unauthorized error when surfing to files

Tags: http, iis, windows-authentication, unauthorized

My IIS is configured to use WindowsAuthentication.

When I surf to the file:

I can see the file perfectly but when i'm checking with charles (http debugger) I see the following result.

[alt text http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/6428/capturea.jpg](http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/6428/capturea.jpg)

The problem is that when a browser does this, it will retry (apperantly up to 3 times) but when .NET (spring.net) tries this, it's crashes after the first attempt saying that I'm unauthorized.

Does anyone has a solution for this? I've been struggeling with this problem for weeks now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this is normal. You may learn more about the conversation between client and server from this KB article,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264921

Then you will know why those 401 messages were there.

Regards,

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring.NET but you should be able to specify a credential which contains user name and password. You can search Spring.NET documentation for hints.